# fs.writefile callback missing

Tags: node.js, file-io, async-await

```
    async writeFile(filePath,fileLines) {
try{
    await fs.writeFile(filePath, fileLines.join('\n'));
} catch(err) {
console.info(err)
}
    }
```

This code throws an error that callback must be a function. But I have already used async/await, then why so? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async/Await does not work for any asynchronous task. The function must return a promise to `await` its value.

You can either use callback functions with the built in `fs` module or find another module.

Comment: What if I use fs.promises? @William